# PHP save cookies declared by Javascript (and possibly all on one page?)

Tags: javascript, php

So, I am working on this PHP submission document, with a login and everything that will save the data (currently through cookies) to a .txt file. As it so unironically turns out, that doesn't work, because JavaScript is used to declare the data after the PHP is loaded. I have spent a few days trying to figure this out, and I believe that I need a 3rd thing for this to work.

The entire thing is split up into two pages, the login and the actual submission page. Once logged in, the submission page uses PHP post to load stuff. This has created problems, because I haven't been able to put a form (for the inputs) on the PHP page.

To combat this, I decided to save it as a cookie using JS, but then quickly realized that PHP will save the cookie BEFORE the JS loads it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Submit your stuff</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Submit your stuff</h1>
    <div align="center">
    <hr>
<!--Here is where the PHP goes-->
    <script id="JS">
    
    
      function SubmitAlert() {
        alert('Your stuff has been Submitted!');
      }
      
      function addstuff() {
        let num = document.getElementById('uploaddiv').getElementsByTagName('textarea').length+1;
        document.getElementById('uploaddiv').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML += '<textarea id="stuff' + num + '" placeholder="Stuff ' + num + '"></textarea>';
      }
      
      function uploadstuff() {
        let stuffinfo = 'let ' + document.getElementById('stuffname').value + ' = {name: ' + document.getElementById('stuffname').value + ', steps: [';
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('uploaddiv').getElementsByTagName('textarea').length; i++) {
          stuffinfo += document.getElementById('uploaddiv').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[i].value + ',';
        }
        stuffinfo += '],};';
        document.cookie = "stuffcookie='" + stuffinfo + "'";
        SubmitAlert();
      }
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And uh, here's the PHP. it's located right above the JavaScript codewise.

```
<?php
  $user = 'sample_user';
  $pass = 'sample_pass';
  $access = false;
  
  if ($_POST['user'] == $user && $_POST['pass'] == $pass) {
    $access = true;
    echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'uploaddiv\').innerHTML += \'<input id="stuffname" name="stuffname" placeholder="Stuff Name"><div><textarea id="stuff1" placeholder="Stuff 1"></textarea></div><button type="button" id="addstuffbutton" onclick="addstuff()">Add stuff</button><button onclick="uploadstuff()" id="submitstuff">Submit your Stuff</button>\';</script>';
  }
  else {
    echo "<h3>You have not been granted access</h3>";
  }
  
  function SaveCookie() {
    $data = $_COOKIE["stuffcookie"].PHP_EOL;
    $file = fopen('test.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
  }
  
?>
```

This is probably going to be the simplest fix ever and I'm stupid to not have realized it.

Comment: As far as i can see you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how things work. Browser requests a page from server (sending cookies if there are has some). Then server generates the page (via PHP in this case) and sends it back to browser (and also might attach some cookies). Browser displays the page and executes JS code. You shouldn't pass user data to server via cookies, there are POST requests for that. Use forms, or some form of AJAX (Fetch API is the modern way).

Comment: Um, I may have worded that a bit word. The login and password get submitted on a separate HTML page, which redirects to this page, which allows you to submit something else.

Answer (score 0):

To Go beyond @Jared commands, a login page can be performed only by PHP, triggered by a form or an AJAX (which is better nowadays as more user friendly). The form by HTML and /or the Ajax by javascript. Then if the password is good you create a [php session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and Check it to détermine if user is still logged over pages. Cookies **must not** store sensitive data as they can be spoofed, edited or deleted, they must only contain a token.